# Sql Query to find duplicates in 2 columns where the values in first column are same

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table where the first column contains States and second column contains Zip Code.  I want to find duplicate Zip Codes in the same State.  So, the first column can have same values but i need to find the duplicates in the second column that have the same values in the first column.

Table :

```
+---+----+------+
| Z | A  |  B   |
+---+----+------+
| 1 | GA | 1234 |
| 2 | GA | 321  |
| 3 | GA | 234  |
| 4 | GA | 9890 |
| 5 | GA | 1234 |
+---+----+------+
```

The query should return the value of the zip code that has a duplicate i.e 1234. I have around 10000+ records.

Thank You.

Comment: Can one zip code occur for more than one state?

Comment: @Rahul - Below answers are correct for what you are describing.  `The above code gives me each zip code (without duplicates) from each state.` => how is that possible with Group by? I'd suggest you to give more sample data and our expected output bases on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `GROUP BY` query and retain zip codes appearing in duplicate.

```
SELECT A, B
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY A, B
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Note that we can group by state and zip code assuming that a given zip code only appears once, for a given state.

Comment: i want to find the zip code that is a duplicate.The above code gives me each zip code (without duplicates) from each state. 

i want to find which state has which zip code that is repeated.

Comment: Edit your question and show us your expected output.  I don't know what you want.

Comment: @Rahul Assuming there are no `NULL` values in the `B` column, do you still see a problem with using `COUNT(*)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT Z AS RecordNumber,
       tblTable.A AS State,
       tblTable.B AS ZipCode
FROM tblTable
JOIN ( SELECT A,
              B
       FROM tblTable
       GROUP BY A,
                B
       HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
     ) AS duplicatesFinder ON tblTable.A = duplicatesFinder.A
                          AND tblTable.B = duplicatesFinder.B
ORDER BY tblTable.A,
         tblTable.B,
         Z;
```

This statement starts with a subquery that selects every unique combination of State and Zip Code that occurs more than once in the source table (which I have called `tblTable` in the absence of the table's name).

The results of this subquery are then joined to the source table based on shared values of State *and* Zip Code.  This `JOIN` effectively eliminates all records from the source table that have a unique State / Zip Code combination from our results dataset.

The list of duplicated States / Zip Codes is then returned along with the values of `Z` associated with each pairing.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

*Appendix*

My code was tetsted against a database created using the following script...

```
CREATE TABLE tblTable
(
    Z   INT,
    A   CHAR( 2 ),
    B   INT
);
INSERT INTO tblTable ( Z,
                       A,
                       B )
VALUES ( 1, 'GA', 1234 ),
       ( 2, 'GA', 321 ),
       ( 3, 'GA', 234 ),
       ( 4, 'GA', 9890 ),
       ( 5, 'GA', 1234 );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select A,B, count(CONCAT_WS('',A,B)) as cnt  from
(select * from yourtable) as a  group by A,B having count(CONCAT_WS('',A,B))>1
```

result for all duplicate records or more than one records:

```
GA  1234    2
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want both rows returned where duplicates are found.  This should work:

```
with cte1 as (
select
   A
  ,B
  ,count(1) over (partition by A, B) as counter
from table_name
)
select
   A
  ,B
from cte1
where 1=1
  and counter > 1
order by A, B
;
```

If you want to know how many duplicate rows there are in total, you can select the "counter" field in the final select:

```
with cte1 as (
select
   A
  ,B
  ,count(1) over (partition by A, B) as counter
from table_name
)
select
   A
  ,B
  ,counter
from cte1
where 1=1
  and counter > 1
order by A, B
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query.

```
SELECT A, B, COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY A, B
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```